# Model field isn't showing up with proper encoding in Django admin

Tags: django, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, django-models

I'm using a Postgresql database with `UTF8` encoding, `en_US.UTF-8` collate and ctype.

Here's the relevant model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='Book_ID')
    lib_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='LIB_ID')
    call_no = models.IntegerField(db_column='Call_no')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='Title')
    alt_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='Alt_Title')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.alt_title
```

From the django shell, I get some weird encoding when printing the object but not when printing `alt_title`.

```
>>> from library.models import Book
>>> book = Book.objects.filter(book_id=2)[0]
>>> book
<Book: ØªÙØ³ÙØ± Ø§ÙÙØ±Ø§Ù Ø§ÙØ¹Ø¸ÙÙ>
>>> book.alt_title
u'\xd8\xaa\xd9\x81\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x82\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb8\xd9\x8a\xd9\x85'
>>> print book
ØªÙØ³ÙØ± Ø§ÙÙØ±Ø§Ù Ø§ÙØ¹Ø¸ÙÙ
```

I also get the same encoding happening in admin interface:
[image: screenshot of admin interface]

Meanwhile, a `select` in psql returns this:
[image: psql select results]

Any ideas at to what's happening?

Comment: I didn't think it was important to mention this but I did import the data into Postgres from MySQL.

Comment: I've got my sql dump file and playing with different encodings, it seems like what Django is displaying is a Western encoding of some sort. It could be Windows 1252, ISO 8859-1, ISO 8859-3, ISO 8859-15.

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` command in your terminal? Also, in your Django app, are you sending encoding headers for the requests?

Comment: @CraigRinger, great question :) ... I was able to solve it with some help (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I did a data import from MySQL into PostgreSQL.

I ensured that the MySQL dump file was encoded in UTF-8.

However, running `\encoding` command in psql, returned 'LATIN1' as the encoding.

It was odd that the `select` returned properly encoded results.

I had SSHed into my server from the Terminal app on OS X. Running `locale` in the remote server returned 'en_US' with no encoding set. As it turns out, since I'm SSHing, the `select` results were being cleaned up by my Terminal app.

So, to fix this:

1. I removed the imported data from the table.
2. Configured the locale to be en_CA.UTF-8. See [this documentation](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu) for details.
3. Re-imported the data using `psql -f<dumpfile> <db>`

The issue it seems was that importing the data, psql had no locale information to work with and assumed LATIN1 was the encoding of the file being imported.